# Shortcodes in HTML like Wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, shortcode

is there a valid way to put multiple divs with just one class. Like a shortcode. For example; i write      but it will contain     . Is it possible? Sorry for bad English.

Comment: No. HTML is not magic.

Comment: You can use JSP to output repeated codeblocks like that.

Comment: You could write a javascript code and invoke that function so that it may create those divs for you. but they would be dynamic might vanish and again reappear once the DOM loads :)

Answer (score 2):

No. HTML provides no way to create extra elements based on classes.

It sounds like you would be better off with some form of template language.

For example, using [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/):

## box.tt

```
<div class="heading"><div class="paragraph"><div class="bottom">
[% content %]
</div></div></div>
```

## page.tt

```
[% WRAPPER box.tt %]
Your content here
[% END %]
```

## Output from TT:

```
<div class="heading"><div class="paragraph"><div class="bottom">

Your content here

</div></div></div>
```

---

You might also be served by [pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#gen-content). They don't sound like a good fit for your problem, but you haven't clearly explained  your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed you put jQuery as a tag in your question.. Using jQuery you could do this

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.box').append('<div class="heading"></div><div class="paragraph"></div><div class="bottom"></div>');
```

But obviously this only happens once the page is loaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/uL9LT/

Answer (score 0):

... Multiple class can be specified but must be delimited with a space

Comment: nope the question was if he can create some logic so that he can have some collection of divs nested. and call them on fly.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of using multiple classes where the red class could control the color.

```
<div class="red box">A</div>
<div class="red heading">B</div>
<div class="red paragraph">C</div>
<div class="red bottom">D</div>
```